# Bearer Authorization is not working on android, but it does fine in iOS

Tags: laravel, react-native, laravel-passport

After trying to use the app on an android device and simulator, the result is the same, I'm getting a 401 (unauthenticated). The problem seems to be weird, as the homescreen does fetch the objects properly, but on another view, same thing, 401 (**only on android**).

The axios call I'm doing is the following:

```
    async getSubject(){
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access');
        const access = 'Bearer ' + token;
        axios.get(`http://example.com/api/auth/subject/${this.props.navigation.getParam('id')}`, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': access,
            }
        })
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({ subject: res.data.subject })
                this.setState({ loading: false });
                this.setState({ refreshing: false })
            })
    }
```

My backend is laravel, I'm using passport. But still, not sure why it only works fine on iOS and **not in android**.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try to add `
    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28" />` in Android manifest file، more info [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24408)

Comment: Hey, let me try it out. Thank you for letting me know, lets see how it goes

Comment: Whoops! That was it. I was using http instead of https. Thank you very much!